# Vuetify Two Images in Carousel-Item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

All I want is to have a carousel-item that contains two images. At the very least I want two carousels side by side. Any ideas since wrapping the carousels in row-cols or simply trying a sheet containning two images in each carousel item does not work.

EDIT : Notice how the component surpasses the right edge of the app drawer (should not happen and also on transition the background of the carousel flashes black. Ideally I get a carousel that is responsive with the two images inside transitionning without flashing black.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="1">
        <v-btn icon large @click="toggle">
          <v-icon>{{ playIcon }}</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-slider 
          color="light-green" 
          thumb-color="light-green accent-4"
          thumb-size="30"
          track-color="light-green accent-4"
          v-model="run" 
          max="19"
          :tick-labels="ticksLabels"
          tick-size="6"
          ticks/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>  
      <v-carousel 
        :cycle="playPause"
        hide-delimiters
        interval=3000
        v-model="run"
        height="700px"
        hide-delimiter-background
        show-arrows-on-hover
        >
        <v-carousel-item
          transition="fade-transition"
          reverse-transition="fade-transition"
          v-for="(item,i) in items"
          :key="i"
          >
          <v-row>
            <v-card width="49%">
              <v-img contain  :src="item.avg"/>
            </v-card>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-card width="49%">
              <v-img contain :src="item.std"/>
            </v-card>
          </v-row>
        </v-carousel-item>
      </v-carousel>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

[image: WHat the code above produces]

Comment: Could you show part of your code? What have you tried?

Comment: @DanielElkington Yes sir. I have added the code and an image of what it produces by editing the original post. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the black flashing by adding these two props to the v-carousel

```
:dark="$vuetify.theme.dark"
:light="!$vuetify.theme.dark"
```

And to fix the scope of the component you can add this style.

```
<style scoped>
.v-carousel .v-window-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.v-carousel-item {
  height: auto;
}
</style>
```